# Drupal 6 to Wordpress migration - media attachments

Tags: attachments, migration

Migrating was simple with a few SQL queries that I found on a blog. But I was unable to find a way to importing images as media attachments on the Wordpress site. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: That's a little more difficult with media in Drupal 6. Is the media being attached to content types in a particular field or is it in the body?

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Yes the media is attached to a CCK file field and not in the body content. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: If you just have the url you can use wp_insert_attachment(); to grab the url of the image and attach it to the right post.

Comment: CCK may be migrated by this wp plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/cms2cms-automated-drupal-to-wp-migration/ however, I'm not sure whether it's possible to migrate attachments separately from the basic content. Anyway, you may try demo migration to see the service in progress.